# JavaFX - bind property from another class onto a status bar

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx, progress-bar

So, I have a very very simple application that is supposed to handle downloading certain files and updating them into a certain directory. The application has a simple interface with a Status Bar that should tell the user how the download process is going. So far, so good.

I have a few implementations of classes that extend the **javafx.concurrent.Task** class. Those classes handle the downloading and saving of files for each system, taking care of the particularities for each one. The download process itself (which actually comes from a remote database) is the same for everyone, so, it's implemented in another class which is called **FileDownloader** as it is, naturally, supposed to be reusable.

So, we have an **UpdateTask** class with a **call()** method that, in turn, calls some method in the **FileDownloader** class.

Trouble is: I would need to bind a **progressProperty** to the bar, but only **UpdateTask** has this property, while most of the work I want to show in the bar is done inside **FileDownloader**. I cannot call updateProgress from within the download method, as it isn't inside the **Task** class. I cannot pass the task into the method and call the update method there. I cannot make a listener on the progress property and listen for changes on the fields inside the downloader class. It seems I cannot do anything and the only real solution would be to count the work being done inside the **call()** method. Woe is me.

Is there a solution for this that doesn't involve me writing less reusable code? Example code as follows:

```
public class UpdateTask extends Task<Void> {

@Override
protected Void call() throws Exception {

//some other operations are performed before this part

FileDownloader downloader = new FileDownloader();

//The stuff I wanna count is in there :(
boolean isDownloaded = downloader.downloadSysVersion();

//some other stuff happens that depends on the completion of the download
}
```

Whoever shows me how to get the information from inside the downloadSysVersion method gets a free internet cookie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a property in the `FileDownloader` class representing the progress. For example, if you wanted to expose the number of bytes downloaded, you could do

```
public class FileDownloader {

    private final ReadOnlyLongWrapper bytesDownloaded = new ReadOnlyLongWrapper();

    public final long getBytesDownloaded() {
        return bytesDownloaded.get();
    }

    public final ReadOnlyLongProperty bytesDownloadedProperty() {
        return bytesDownloaded.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    private long totalBytes ;

    public long getTotalBytes() {
        return totalBytes ;
    }

    // other code as before...

    public boolean downloadSysVersion() {
        // code as before, but periodically call
        bytesDownloaded.set(...);
        // ...
    }

}
```

Now you do

```
@Override
protected Void call() throws Exception {

    FileDownloader downloader = new FileDownloader();

    downloader.bytesDownloadedProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
        updateProgress(newValue.longValue(), downloader.getTotalBytes()));

    boolean isDownloaded = downloader.downloadSysVersion();

    // ...
}
```

If you want to make the `FileDownloader` class independent of the entire JavaFX API (including the property classes), you can use a `LongConsumer` instead:

```
public class FileDownloader {

    private LongConsumer progressUpdate ;

    public void setProgressUpdate(LongConsumer progressUpdate) {
        this.progressUpdate = progressUpdate ;
    }

    private long totalBytes ;

    public long getTotalBytes() {
        return totalBytes ;
    }

    public boolean downloadSysVersion() {
        // periodically do
        if (progressUpdate != null) {
            progressUpdate.accept(...); // pass in number of bytes downloaded
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

and in this case your task looks like

```
@Override
protected Void call() throws Exception {

    FileDownloader downloader = new FileDownloader();

    downloader.setProgressUpdate(bytesDownloaded -> 
        updateProgress(bytesDownloaded, downloader.getTotalBytes()));

    boolean isDownloaded = downloader.downloadSysVersion();

    // ...
}
```

With either of these setups, you can then just bind the progress bar's `progressProperty` to the task's `progressProperty` as usual.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I opted for the ReadOnlyLongWrapper in the end, as this is supposed to be a real simple application and I only need some degree of decoupling anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In your UpdateTask class, add:

```
@Override
    public void updateProgress(double workDone, double max) {
        super.updateProgress(workDone, max);
    }
```

You'll need to pass the UpdateTask instance to your FileDownlader instance instance somehow, probably thru constructor, or however.
Then you should be able to call updateProgress.

Comment: That makes the `FileDownloader` less reusable, though, as it would then have a dependency on the `UpdateTask`

Comment: Sry. It seems I don't understand what exactly does he want.

Comment: I tried that approach and it doesn't work, as it seems I can only call the updateProgress method from within the call method. Yes it would make it less usable, but I tried it anyway out of desperation.