# How to update a JavaFX progress indicator based on progress of separate classes?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a program consisting of 4 classes:

1) **GUI.java** - Program containing the JavaFX progress indicator GUI

2) **mainRun.java** - A 'master' class that runs task1.java and task2.java. In the actual program, mainRun.java will be responsible for consolidating several information from task1.java and task2.java, hence, this class is required.

3) **task1.java** - A program that will run BEFORE task2.java

4) **task2.java** - A program that will run AFTER task1.java

I would like to update GUI.java's progress indicator based on the updateProgress(X,Y) function from task1.java and task2.java.

However, mainRun.java will be the program calling task1.java and after, task2.java. Hence, GUI.java's progress indicator will only update its progress based on the updateProgress(X,Y) function called from mainRun.java.

**How can I update GUI.java's progress indicator whenever updateProgress(X,Y) function is run in task1.java and task2.java (possibly bypassing mainRun.java?)?**

**Otherwise, is there a way where mainRun.java can actively be notified of an updateProgress(X,Y) from task1.java and task2.java and update GUI.java's progress indicator whenever it is notified?**

Here is a mock pseudo example of the problem I am describing:

**GUI.java**

```
public class GUI extends Application {
   private mainRun mainTask;
   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
       final ProgressIndicator progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator(0);
       final Button startButton = new Button("Start");

       // Start Button.
       startButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
           @Override
           public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
               mainTask = new mainRun();
               progressIndicator.progressProperty().unbind();
               progressIndicator.setProgress(0);
               progressIndicator.progressProperty().unbind();
            progressIndicator.progressProperty().bind(mainTask.progressProperty());
               new Thread(mainTask).start();
           }
       });
       ... JavaFX stage code ...
   }
}
```

**mainRun.java**

```
public class CopyTask extends Task<String> {

@Override
protected String call() throws Exception {

    /** Update GUI.java's progress bar based on t1 here **/

    task1 t1 = new task1();
    ProgressIndicator progress = new ProgressIndicator(0);
    progress.progressProperty().unbind();
    progress.setProgress(0);
    progress.progressProperty().bind(t1.progressProperty());

    new Thread(t1).start();
    t1.addEventHandler(WorkerStateEvent.WORKER_STATE_SUCCEEDED, //
          new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

              @Override
              public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {

              /** Continue updating GUI.java's progress bar based on t2 here **/

                  task2 t2 = new task2();
                  progress.progressProperty().unbind();
                  progress.progressProperty().bind(t2.progressProperty());
                  new Thread(t2).start();
              }
          });
        return "Done";
    } 
}
```

**task1.java**

```
public class task1 extends Task<String> {
    protected String call() throws Exception {
        for (int i =0; i<1000; i++) {
            this.updateProgress(i,2000); // currently updates mainRun.java progress bar NOT GUI.java
        }
    return "";
    } 
}
```

**task2.java**

```
public class task2 extends Task<String> {
    protected String call() throws Exception {
        for (int i =1000; i<2000; i++) {
            this.updateProgress(i,2000); // currently updates mainRun.java progress bar NOT GUI.java
        }
    return "";
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Found the solution thanks to user c0der:

> progressIndicator.progressProperty().bind(copyTask.t1.progressProperty().add(copyTask.t2.progressProperty()));**

**UPDATE:**
Found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31734527/javafx-bind-property-from-another-class-onto-a-status-bar) which resolved all problems perfectly with a solid example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it by binding progressbar's progress property to **two** progress properties :

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TwoLongProcessWithOneProgressBar extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws InterruptedException {

        BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();

        FlowPane topPane = new FlowPane(Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 5.,5.);
        topPane.setPadding(new Insets(20.));

        Panel panel = new Panel();
        BorderPane.setAlignment(panel, Pos.CENTER);

        Button button = new Button("Start");
        button.setDefaultButton(true);
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            panel.runLlongTask();
            button.setDisable(true);
        });
        topPane.getChildren().add(button);
        mainPane.setTop(topPane);

        mainPane.setCenter(panel);
        mainPane.setBottom(panel.getBar());

        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, Color.WHITE);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.centerOnScreen();
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class Panel extends HBox{

    private final ProgressBar bar;

    Panel(){
        setPrefSize(150,50);
        bar = new ProgressBar();
        bar.prefWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty());
    }

    void runLlongTask() {
        Task task1 = new Task1();
        Thread th1 = new Thread(task1);
        th1.setDaemon(true);

        Task task2 = new Task2();
        Thread th2 = new Thread(task2);
        th2.setDaemon(true);
        //bind progress bar to both task progress property
        bar.progressProperty().bind(task1.progressProperty().add(task2.progressProperty()));
        th1.start();
        th2.start();
    }

    ProgressBar getBar() {  return bar; }
}

class Task1 extends Task<Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        for (int i =0; i<1000; i++) {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
            updateProgress(i,2000);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class Task2 extends Task<Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        for (int i =0; i<1000; i++) {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
            updateProgress(i,2000);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi c0der, thanks for your response. Binding two progress properties together does not seem feasible for my problem as the program (mainRun.java) that programmed to run task1 and task2 does not contain the progress indicator. Instead it is GUI.java that contains the indicator - which does not know about task1 and task2.

Comment: Oh wait! It worked! I used: progress.progressProperty().bind(mainRun.t1.progressProperty().add(mainRun.t2.progressProperty())); Thank you so much!!!

Comment: In my example The progress bar is part of the gui, not the task. I am glad it helped.